# CPTTextLayer - multiple lines NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, core-plot, nsattributedstring

I am trying to use NSAttributedString in CPTAnnotation with line break.
When using the code below, only the "firstString..." is displayed.
When removing the \n sign, both strings are properly displayed (sizes and colors proper), but in one line.

Is it possible to use something similar to label's numberOfLines=0 (enables line breaking) on CPTTextLayer used in annotation?

```
    NSMutableAttributedString* finalString = [firstAttrStr mutableCopy];
    NSMutableAttributedString *newLineAttrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n"];
    [finalLabel appendAttributedString:newLineAttrStr];
    [finalLabel appendAttributedString:secondAttrStr];

    //additional setup in here
    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithAttributedText:finalLabel];

    textLayer.fill            = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
    textLayer.cornerRadius    = 3.0;
    textLayer.paddingLeft     = 0.5;
    textLayer.paddingTop      = 0.5;
    textLayer.paddingRight    = 0.5;
    textLayer.paddingBottom   = 0.5;
    textLayer.hidden          = NO;

    //add shadow
    textLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    textLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    textLayer.shadowRadius = 5;
    textLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;

    _highlightAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:@[middlePoint, yAnnotationPosition]];
    [_highLightPlot addAnnotation:_highlightAnnotation];

    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithAttributedText:finalString];
    _highlightAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
```

It looks like that:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the annotation displayed? Is it possible that the second line is being clipped by the edge of the plot area? Core Plot won't automatically adjust the layout to make sure the whole label is visible.

Comment: I've added the screenshot. It is definitely not cropped by plot area.

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? Does this occur on both the simulator and a device, or just one of them? What version of iOS are you testing with?

Comment: Podflie.lock says: CorePlot (2.0)

Comment: Try Core Plot 2.1.

Comment: Unfortunately the same in 2.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110685/discussion-between-eric-skroch-and-izik461).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions of Eric, I solved it.
The problem was with the font: Antenna. When using other fonts, annotation is displayed properly.